# NSAttributedString properties changes after file archiving

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextview, nsattributedstring, nstextattachment

I have some `NSAttributedString`s to display. The `NSAttributedString` contains an `NSAttachment` which is an image with specific size. First time it s been displayed correctly in `UITextView`.

Then I have stored it in an `NSMutableArray` and archived it. When I reload the `NSAttributedString` from archive file to `UITextView` , the attached image looses it's size properties !!!

Is there any problem in storing `NSAttributedString` with attachements in file archiving ??